# Python join dataframes by index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working with multiple dataframes in Python and I'm looking to map one onto the other based on a common column (similar to index/match in Excel). I want to join the `date` column of one dataframe, to the `index` of the other dataframe (where the date is stored as the index). How would I call out the index? For reference, I want to subtract my ROI for dataframe 2 (`awk_price`) to the ROI from dataframe 1 (`S&P 500`). The dataframes are shown below.

I currently have a merged dataframe using

```py
pd.merge(awk_price,sp_500, left_index=True, right_on='Date')
```

I would love to just add a column to df2 subtracting ROI from dataframe 2 by ROI from dataframe 1 but I can't figure out how to "map" the `dates` column from dataframe 1 to the index from dataframe 2.

[Dataframe 2 (awk_price)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCsQ5.png)

[Dataframe 1 (sp_500)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwydT.png)

Comment: Please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the [Meta FAQ entry Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)

Comment: All code, data, error messages, and relevant info must be embedded within the body of the question, *without* relying on any external links. It also must be in text format, so users can quickly copy-paste (error free) into their editors, browsers, or search engines. Additionally, text in photos can be difficult to read, especially on mobile devices. Please edit  to embed data as text, as any post  that does not meet SO guidelines is subject to removal. Posts dependant on an external link could become useless if the link were to become unreachable, or the page changes, & SO quality would suffer

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reset_index()`, and then `rename` the column:

```
df=df1.reset_index().rename(columns={"index": "Date"})
df
```